# SQL question, find properties have been viewed by client

Tags: sql

I need help please, I'm trying to add have a condition the property has been viewed

- Table client (clientno {pk}, fname, lname, email, ...)
- Table propertyForRent (propertyno {pk}, street, ....)
- Table viewing (clientno, propertyno, ...)

I need to list `fname, lname, proprtyno, street, email`

This is my SQL attempt:

```
SELECT 
    fname, lname, Viewing.propertyno, street, email 
FROM
    Viewing 
INNER JOIN
    PropertyForRent ON Viewing.propertyno = PropertyForRent.propertyno
INNER JOIN 
    Client ON Viewing.clientno = Client.clientno
ORDER BY 
    fname
```

Comment: what is the exact question that you are asking? And what have you tried so far? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Since we don't know your database structure, you're going to have to tell us which field indicates that the property has been viewed.

Comment: can you write a minimum representative example perhaps with a table structure `create table client ( clientno int, fname varchar, lname varchar ...)` ? Be precise about exactly what you want to see as output. You're more likely to get a decent answer this way!

Comment: The SQL looks reasonable - what is the problem? Are you getting an error - if so **WHAT** error exactly? Are you just not getting the expected data? If so, then please provide some sample data and explain what you're getting, and what you were expecting to get....

Comment: iii. Write an SQL statement to list all the properties that have been viewed by one or more clients more than 2 times. More precisely, list the client full name, the client email, the propertyNo, the street of the property, and all the viewings that occurred for that property. Order the output first by the client fName, then by the propertyNo (screenshot required)

Comment: @tonychen that doesn't answer any of our questions or tell us any more information than you originally gave us. Instead of parroting your homework question at us, please actually pay attention to what you have been asked, and try to answer us. Otherwise we cannot help you, and this question is a waste of our (free) time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this if this helps

```
   SELECT 
   fname, lname, v.propertyno, 
   street, email 
  FROM
   Viewing v where v.propertyno IS NOT 
        NULL 
    INNER JOIN
     PropertyForRent p ON 
     v.propertyno =  p.propertyno
       INNER JOIN 
      Client ON Viewing.clientno = 
      Client.clientno
      ORDER BY 
       fname
```

Comment: you're assuming that an entry in "viewing" indicates that the property has been viewed. But it could just be a record that a viewing is booked. We don't know if there's a field in there which indicates that the viewing actually took place - we need the OP to explain the meaning and details of the schema, which so far they haven't done despite being requested to do so.

Comment: surely better to save your time, follow the question and then write an answer once you can be sure what the answer actually is? Up to you though, of course.